Redundand queries to the `pg_catalog.pg_type` table
I'm using Next.JDBC with the official Postgres driver and HickaryCP pool. Every time I query something that involves JSONb, I see some extra queries in the console, like:
SELECT n.nspname = ANY(current_schemas(true)), n.nspname, t.typname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON t.typnamespace = n.oid 
WHERE t.oid = $1
parameters: $1 = '3802'

SELECT typinput='pg_catalog.array_in'::regproc as is_array, typtype, typname, pg_type.oid   FROM pg_catalog.pg_type   
LEFT JOIN (select ns.oid as nspoid, ns.nspname, r.r           from pg_namespace as ns           join ( select s.r, (current_schemas(false))[s.r] as nspname                    from generate_series(1, array_upper(current_schemas(false), 1)) as s(r) ) as r          using ( nspname )        ) as sp     
ON sp.nspoid = typnamespace  WHERE pg_type.oid = $1  ORDER BY sp.r, pg_type.oid DESC
parameters: $1 = '3802'

They return:
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------
?column? | t
nspname  | pg_catalog
typname  | jsonb

-[ RECORD 1 ]---
is_array | f
typtype  | b
typname  | jsonb
oid      | 3802

Is there is a way to tweak the driver, pool, or connection settings to avoid spamming these queries all the time?

I'm using the same libraries and I've never seen those queries being run. I also can't find anything relevant in the sources of the whole classpath of a project that uses those libraries. Can you use a debugger to trace where these are coming from? You also mention that you see the queries "in the console" - which console?

Ah, I didn't have sources for the Pg JDBC driver. It seems that at least the second query is generated by org.postgresql.jdbc.PgDatabaseMetaData#getTypeInfo which gets called by next.jdbc when you navigate to :typeInfo using nav.

Just tried debugging on my end - the code for the second query doesn't run at all. But I also don't use nav anywhere. I assume it might be called by something that you use - e.g. tools like Portal or Reveal.

@EugenePakhomov by the console, I mean the Postgres process run with -E flag which means logging all the incoming queries, event produces by a driver on low level.

The only things I know that use -E is the CLI client psql and the single-user mode of postgres. Per the docs psql: Echo the actual queries generated by \d and other backslash commands..  For single-user mode the action is Echo all commands to standard output before executing them, though not sure why you would be using that?
